# Can't compile latex3 regexp

Tags: latex3

I just wrote a code involving a simple regexp, but it is MUCH slower than a string search (at least 100x slower). So to optimize it, I tried to compile the regex, unfortunately it is giving me a compilation error:

```
Braced quantifier '{' may not be followed by '_'
```

Any idea what I did wrong?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_extract_all:nnN { VVN, nVN }
\str_new:N \l__robExt_my_str
\str_set:Nn \l__robExt_my_str {I like \vegetable and \fruit.}

% Without compilation, this is fine
\regex_extract_all:nVN { \\[A-Za-z]+ } \l__robExt_my_str \l__robExt_output_seq
\show\l__robExt_output_seq

% We compile the regex: we get an error
\regex_const:Nn \l__robExt_macro_regex { \\[A-Za-z]+ }
\regex_extract_all:VVN \l__robExt_macro_regex \l__robExt_my_str \l__robExt_output_seq
\show\l__robExt_output_seq

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since the `l3regex` functions are designed for token lists, why are you turning token lists into strings? You name the constant in a way which suggests you're extracting macros, but you're not.

Comment: @cfr I am using a string because in theory this might not always contains latex stuff, and strings are quite convenient to use (see my library https://github.com/leo-colisson/robust-externalize, this post is to optimize `auto forward`)

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution, I need to generate the `NVN` variant from `NnN` and not `nnN`. It is maybe 25% faster, but still significantly slower than I'd imagine. If someone knows why regex are slow, I'd love to hear it.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_extract_all:nnN { VVN, nVN }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_extract_all:NnN { NVN }

\str_new:N \l__robExt_my_str
\str_set:Nn \l__robExt_my_str {I like \vegetable and \fruit.}

% Without compilation, this is fine

\regex_extract_all:nVN { \\[A-Za-z]+ } \l__robExt_my_str \l__robExt_output_seq
\show\l__robExt_output_seq

% We compile the regex: we get an error
\regex_const:Nn \l__robExt_macro_regex { \\[A-Za-z]+ }
\regex_show:N \l__robExt_macro_regex
\regex_extract_all:NVN \l__robExt_macro_regex \l__robExt_my_str \l__robExt_output_seq
\show\l__robExt_output_seq

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
I don't know why, but in my tests it seems like regex search `\regex_match:nVTF` or `\regex_extract_all:NVN` is significantly slower than `\str_if_in:NnTF`. Here is my benchmark file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
% grab latest .sty file from https://github.com/leo-colisson/robust-externalize/
\usepackage{robust-externalize}
\robExtConfigure{
  % If you do not want to enable shell-escape, just manually
  % inspect benchmark-robExt-compile-missing-figures.sh
  % and run "bash benchmark-robExt-compile-missing-figures.sh"
  enable fallback to manual mode,
  compile in parallel after=3,
}

\cacheEnvironment{forest}{
  latex,
  add to preamble={
    \usepackage{forest}
  },
  % Uncomment one line at a time to compare efficiency:
  % (ordered by faster -> slower)
  % 2.86s (adding one "if matches" seems to add around 0.01s, try to add dummy matches to test)
  %if matches={mainName}{forward=\mainName},
  % 3.37s (adding one "if matches" seems to add around 1s, if you uncomment the last the compilation will go to 14s)
  %if matches regex={mainName}{forward=\mainName},
  % 5.21s ==> that's the time I'd like to optimize the most.
  auto forward,
  %%% Just to see that matches takes a really different time from matches regex:
  % Adds ~10s!
  % if matches regex={xxxxA}{},
  % if matches regex={xxxxB}{},
  % if matches regex={xxxxC}{},
  % if matches regex={xxxxD}{},
  % if matches regex={xxxxE}{},
  % if matches regex={xxxxF}{},
  % if matches regex={xxxxG}{},
  % if matches regex={xxxxH}{},
  % if matches regex={xxxxI}{},
  % if matches regex={xxxxJ}{},
}


\NewDocumentCommandAutoForward{\mainName}{}{John}

\begin{document}
\foreach \j in {0,...,200}{
  % This is always the same picture, this mostly drastically reduces the first compilation time
  % without significantly changing the next runs, which is what we try to optimize right now
  \begin{forest}
    [\mainName
    [\mainName [\mainName]]
    [\mainName
    [\mainName [\mainName]]
    [\mainName[\mainName]]
    [\mainName[D[a]][NP[\mainName]]]
    ]
    ]
  \end{forest}\\
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no `NVN` in your question, so how can this possibly answer it? Isn't the point that's the variant you **need**? As opposed to how to generate it?

Comment: compilation will only be faster if you use the regexp multiple times. given the entire regexp engine is written in tex macros 100x slower than a single tex delimited argument expansion would be impressively fast

Comment: @cfr yes, but before when I was trying to generate it I was getting an error like "generating N is deprecated, use V" that's why I used V. Actually, I'm not so sure to understand why V fails here, I think of V as a "clever" N but obviously it is not ^^'

Comment: if the argument is `\foo` defined as `\def\foo{abc}`  and you pass it to an `N` variant that function  gets passed `\foo`. If you pass it to a `V` variant, the function gets passed `{abc}` so it's not so much that `V` is clever and `N` is not, they are just  completely different.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Be kind to Bruno, he did such amazing feat. In the example above the difference in compilation is not perceptible. On the colorizer program I am working with regexes  compilation is x4-5 slower. Takes 1 minute with nocolor and 4-5.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides yes I'm always kind:-) that's what I meant. If you compare with replacing `a` by `b` using `\def\foo#1a{#1b}`   which will do the replacement in one expansion step, then implementing a regexp engine in expandable macros that works within a factor of 100 would be astonishing efficient code, not something that deserves "If someone knows why regex are slow," :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149601/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-tobiasbora).