# Efficiently program search of macro in string

Tags: latex3

As a follow-up question to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700794/cant-compile-latex3-regexp/700796?noredirect=1#comment1742486_700796), I realized that `\regex_extract_all` is really slow compared to `\str_if_in`. My goal is the following: I have a list/hash table `L` of macros, and a string `s` (I'd prefer if it stays a string rather than a token list… but I might be able to use the original token list instead so if the solution is faster with the original token list I guess I can live with it): my goal is to extract all macros from `s` that belong to `L`. There are two options I see:

- use a loop on `L` and check if the macro is in the string with `\str_if_in`. Problem: this scales like `|s| x |L|` that might get large (maybe `L` has a few hundred elements)
- use a regex on `s` to extract all macros and check if they are in the hash table `L`: This scales like `|s|`, but problem: regex are really slow in LaTeX.

So my question is: can I write a specialized version of `\regex_extract_all` that would be able to efficiently extract macros?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_extract_all:nnN { VVN, nVN }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_extract_all:NnN { NVN }

\str_new:N \l__robExt_my_str
\str_set:Nn \l__robExt_my_str {I like \vegetable and \fruit.}

\regex_const:Nn \l__robExt_macro_regex { \\[A-Za-z]+ }
\regex_show:N \l__robExt_macro_regex
\regex_extract_all:NVN \l__robExt_macro_regex \l__robExt_my_str \l__robExt_output_seq
\show\l__robExt_output_seq % I need a more efficient way to get this list

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: your question is a bit contradictory, you say you want the source to be a string (`str` type  in expl3) so it only has catcode 12 or 10 characters, then you ask for looking for macros?

Comment: if you had a `tl` you could look for the single token `\vegetable` very quickly, but as you have the detokenized string you need to look for `\ v e g e t a b l e`  which is 10 comparisons rather than 1 (at some level)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So, in my library robust-externalize, I convert any input to a string directly because it is easier for me to work with it as it might contain non-latex stuff etc. So in that case, what I call a macro is a string that starts with a backslash (catcode 12) and contains a sequence of letters. But I can also write the original token list separately if needed, so in that case a macro would be the usual macros (I guess this might be more efficient to parse)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, so let's assume that I have a token list, that's fine. From a `tl`, how would you loop over all macros it contains? Ohhh… maybe a simple `\tl_map_inline` would work, and then identifying macros based on catcode or similar? What is the proper way to do that check?

Comment: So in summary: You don't have control over your input and can't be sure whether typesetting it into a box register is save, correct?

Comment: Also: do you really need a sequence containing all macros found in the input, or is a direct comparison against a list of macros better? Do you then need a list of macros that are found, or just a true/false whether any of them is contained?

Comment: @Skillmon I don't have any control on the input, and I don't even want to typeset it as I will write this string in a file without even typesetting anything. I want to know which macros are present, or rather execute a code stored in `\mycodes@MYMACRO` if it exists.

Comment: @tobiasBora so we don't even want a list of macros, we want to execute code... Wait a second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMHO, most effective solution of your task looks like this:

```
\def\registerL#1{\expandafter\def\csname L:\string#1\endcsname {}}

\def\getfromstring#1{\normalbraces#1\def\listmacros{}\expandafter\getfromstringA#1\getfromstringA}
\def\getfromstringA#1{\ifx#1\getfromstringA \else
   \ifcsname L:\string#1\endcsname \addto\listmacros{#1}\fi
   \expandafter\getfromstringA\fi
}
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\let\ea=\expandafter
\def\normalbraces#1{{\catcode`{=12 \catcode`}=12 \everyeof={\endfile}%
   \ea\normalbracesA\ea#1\scantokens\ea{#1}}}
\def\normalbracesA#1#2\endfile{\gdef#1{#2}}

\registerL \vegetable
\registerL \fruit

\def\mystring{I like {\vegetable and} \fruit.}

\getfromstring\mystring

{\tt \meaning\listmacros} % prints  macro:->\vegetable \fruit 

\bye
```

The macros which you want to search are registered by `\registerL \macro`. It means they are stored in hash table (with very quick searching). Next, the `\getfromstring` macro scans given string token per token and if the token is registered macro, then the token is saved to the `\listmacros` by `\addto` macro.

You can do your benchmark tests with this solution. I am sure that there isn't solution with better speed.

Comment: +1 I was thinking of the same thing,  more or less:-) You might want to note it needs a bit of extra code if the original string can have brace groups.

Comment: Thanks a lot, unfortunately, as pointed by @DavidCarlisle it fails if it contains a brace inside like `I like { \vegetable and \fruit }`

Comment: I added OpTeX trick 0120 http://petr.olsak.net/optex/optex-tricks.html#prepmac which solves your problem: `\normalbraces\macro` resets catcode of `{` and `}` to 12 before scanning. It is based to `\scantextokens` available only in LuaTeX. If you want to use a different TeX engine, then you have to use `\scantokens` instead `\scantextokens` which makes your headache with "file ended during scanning def". It can by solved by more tricks. Note, the `\replstring` mentioned in the OpTeX trick (and defined in OpTeX only) is unnecessary in your task because ignoring spaces in not problem here.

Comment: Thanks, so I tried to add ```\def\normalbraces#1{{\catcode`{=12 \catcode`}=12 \expandafter}\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{\scantokens\expandafter{#1}}}
\normalbraces\mystring``` before the `\getfromstring\mystring` but I get exactly this error `ERROR: File ended while scanning definition of \mystring.`, is it what you meant? What is the trick to solve it? (I want to support pdflatex as well)

Comment: OK, see my edit. But it is better to support only LuaTeX (for example OpTeX does it). Things are much more simple.

Comment: Awesome, it is exactly what I needed, the whole compilation time went from 5.5s to 2.75s on my benchmark, while without it is is around 2.6s… so fairly good!

Comment: And yes, luatex is certainly simpler to support, sadly for libraries users might need to use pdflatex for other reasons.

Comment: @tobiasBora note that `\scantokens` might alter the contents of your input if the input was given with other category codes in effect than when you execute it (shouldn't be a real issue, just wanted to give a small warning, otherwise this is a very solid solution).

Comment: @Skillmon Ok thanks! I got warned a few times against `\scantokens` but was never sure what could go wrong with it. I guess it is part of the answer :-)

Comment: @tobiasBora `\scantokens` is just notoriously hard to use correctly, so the advice for beginners is usually to be careful around it or not use it at all.

Comment: @tobiasBora in this instance, `\normalbraces` might add a trailing space to the token list, but since we don't care about spaces this doesn't hurt. It'll also not generally add a trailing space, whether it adds one depends on the contents.

Comment: I actually discovered another edge case: this breaks if some parts are surrounded by `\begin{foo} \end{foo}`, like `\def\mystring{I like {\vegetable and}, \fruits, and \begin{foo} \pasta \end{foo}.}`. The error is different in my real-life test (it prints me like `\pasta` is undefined) and in this MWE (I get `ERROR: Paragraph ended before \end  was complete.`), but I’m suspecting that fixing one error might fix the other one. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @tobiasBora corrected.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick correction!

Answer (score 3):

The following implements an expandable search for your macros using `etl`.

The macro `\__robExt_extract_macros:n` uses that expandable search to assign a list of all found macros to a sequence. This works on the `tl` version of the input, and works correctly for any level of groups. The code should be sufficiently fast.

I benchmarked your `\regex_extract_all:NVN` usage against my `\__robExt_extract_macros:n`, my implementation was 38 times faster while doing more (which is still kind-of-slow, if the list of macros to search for is fixed one could combine my loop and @wipet's check based on `\ifcsname` to get faster).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{etl}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__robExt_macro_searcher:nn #1#2
  {
    % search in the tl #1 for all macros contained in #2
    \__robExt_macro_searcher_aux:en
      { \__robExt_macro_searcher_prepare:n {#2} }
      {#1}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__robExt_macro_searcher_prepare:n #1
  { \tl_map_tokens:nn {#1} { {} \exp_not:n } }
\cs_new:Npn \__robExt_macro_searcher_aux:nn
  {
    \etl_act:nnnnn
      \__robExt_macro_searcher_search:nN
      \use_none:n
      \__robExt_macro_searcher_aux:nn
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__robExt_macro_searcher_aux:nn { e }
\cs_new:Npn \__robExt_macro_searcher_search:nN #1#2
  {
    \__robExt_macro_searcher_cmp_loop:Nw #2 #1
    \prg_break: {} \prg_break: {} \prg_break: {} \prg_break: {}
    \prg_break_point:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__robExt_macro_searcher_cmp_loop:Nw #1 #2#3 #4#5 #6#7 #8#9
  {
    #2 \etl_token_if_eq:NNT #1 #3 \__robExt_macro_searcher_output:w
    #4 \etl_token_if_eq:NNT #1 #5 \__robExt_macro_searcher_output:w
    #6 \etl_token_if_eq:NNT #1 #7 \__robExt_macro_searcher_output:w
    #8 \etl_token_if_eq:NNT #1 #9 \__robExt_macro_searcher_output:w
    \__robExt_macro_searcher_cmp_loop:Nw #1
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__robExt_macro_searcher_output:w
    #1 \__robExt_macro_searcher_cmp_loop:Nw #2
  { \exp_not:N #2 \prg_break: }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nne }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__robExt_extract_macros:n #1
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nne \l__robExt_output_seq {}
      { \__robExt_macro_searcher:nn {#1} { \vegetable \fruit } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\__robExt_extract_macros:n {I like \vegetable and \fruit.}
\seq_show:N \l__robExt_output_seq % I need a more efficient way to get this list

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

---

If only a fixed set of macros is searched, and specific code to be executed if they are found (and the real list doesn't interest us at all), we can as well implement just that (this makes the `etl`-based implementation much simpler!):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{etl}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__robExt_setup_protected_action:Nn #1#2
  { \cs_new_protected:cpn { __robExt_action_ \token_to_str:N #1 : } {#2} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__robExt_setup_action:Nn #1#2
  { \cs_new:cpn { __robExt_action_ \token_to_str:N #1 : } {#2} }

\cs_new:Npn \__robExt_macro_searcher:n
  {
    \etl_act:nnnnn
      \__robExt_macro_searcher_search:nN
      \use_none:n
      { \use_i:nn \__robExt_macro_searcher:n }
      {}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__robExt_macro_searcher_aux:nn { e }
\cs_new:Npn \__robExt_macro_searcher_search:nN #1#2
  {
    \cs_if_exist:cT { __robExt_action_ \token_to_str:N #2 : }
      { \exp_not:c { __robExt_action_ \token_to_str:N #2 : } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\__robExt_setup_protected_action:Nn \vegetable
  { \typeout { \noexpand \vegetable used } }
\__robExt_setup_protected_action:Nn \fruit
  { \typeout { \noexpand \fruit used } }

\__robExt_macro_searcher:n {I like \vegetable and \fruit.}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

which prints

```
\vegetable used
\fruit used
```

to the log/terminal.

Comment: Whoo thanks, that's a quite complicated one ^^' But yes, the list of tokens is fixed so `\csname` is usable so I guess we can make it more efficient this way.

Comment: Out of curiosity,  would it make sense to put it in a `\tl` and simply use `\tl_map`? I struggle to understand this solution ^^'

Comment: @tobiasBora `\tl_map` doesn't step into braces, so no, that wouldn't result in the correct behaviour.

Comment: @tobiasBora the searched macro names are always only letters, no spaces, no weird symbols, right?

Comment: Oh I see, that's annoying indeed… why is it the case? They consider a group as a single element? Yes, the searched macro names are just normal letter-based macros.

Comment: And I read that `elt` is slower than normal `tl`, is there any reason we use elt? Do we really care if it is expandable or not?

Comment: @tobiasBora yes, `\tl_map_...` functions consider a group as a single element. `\etl_act:nnnnn` allows acting on a token list and defining actions for `N`-type tokens, spaces, and groups. We recurse into groups in the code above.

Comment: @tobiasBora there is no user-space macro in `tl` for the kind of loop we're after (stepping into groups). The `etl` things that are slower are things like `\tl_replace_...` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update, it is indeed much clearer now, the first code was really mysterious to me (especially `\__robExt_macro_searcher_cmp_loop`)!

Comment: @tobiasBora `\__robExt_macro_searcher_cmp_loop` is just a fast `\tl_map_function:nN`-like loop that uses the special structure we created with `\__robExt_macro_searcher_prepare:n` to loop over the list of macro-names without any explicit stop-condition (instead the stop condition will be the `\prg_break:`s we inserted after `#1`). We could use `\tl_map_function:nN` instead.

Comment: Oh I see. And you add many `\prg_break:` to limit the probability of stopping in case the `\prg_break:` symbol was part of the code? So if a code has like 4 `\prg_break` in a row it would break? (not saying it is a problem in practice, just curious)

Comment: @tobiasBora no, with each iteration of the loop I check up to 4 control sequences, hence if the number of macros you want to test for is divisable by 4 I need 4 additional valid arguments, that's why we need 4. The only marcos that must not be part of the macros you want to search for are `\prg_break_point:` and `\__robExt_macro_searcher_cmp_loop:Nw` (though both would work if they were the first in the list and the other not part of the list).

Comment: Oh it is faster this way? And if it is not divisable by 4, then you will have a few `\prg_break` left, but this would not affect the computation?

Comment: @tobiasBora less looping-overhead, so yes, this should be faster (I didn't benchmark it though), also, no they are not left there, they are removed by the first `\prg_break:` that gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that every searched macro does not contain a space in its name, the following is a string based solution that should be pretty fast.

We use the fact that after `\tl_to_str:n` every control word starts with the current `\escapechar` (which we actively set, though in practice this should be a backslash most of the time) and ends with a space. So we grab everything between these two and assume that's the macro name. This way we can work ourselves through the list pretty fast, and we terminate by a known macro name that also fulfills that criteria. Also, we put a `~` at the end of the user input to make sure we gracefully fail if some unexpected input is found.

To not get tripped by a control symbol we need to test whether the first token after each backslash is in `[A-Za-z]`. That test is what takes the most time in this.

I benchmarked it against the `etl` code, and for the input `I like \vegetable and \fruit.` this approach is slightly faster (ca. 160 vs. ca. 175 ops), but as soon as three control symbols show up (`I \\ \> \< like \vegetable and \fruit.`) this takes considerably longer (ca. 300 ops vs ca 230 ops). So which of the two to prefer depends on how many control symbols show up.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__robExt_setup_protected_action:Nn #1#2
  { \cs_new_protected:cpn { __robExt_action_ \cs_to_str:N #1 : } {#2} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__robExt_setup_action:Nn #1#2
  { \cs_new:cpn { __robExt_action_ \cs_to_str:N #1 : } {#2} }
\cs_new_protected:Npe \__robExt_search_macros:n #1
  {
    \exp_not:n
      {
        \group_begin:
          \tex_escapechar:D = `\\ \exp_stop_f:
          \exp_last_unbraced:NNo
        \group_end:
        \__robExt_search_macros:w \tl_to_str:n
      }
      { #1 } ~ \tl_to_str:n { \robExt_search_macros_done: }
  }
\__robExt_setup_action:Nn \robExt_search_macros_done: { \use_none:n }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \use_ii_i:nn { e }
\use_ii_i:en { \char_generate:nn { `\\ } { 12 } } { \cs_new:Npn \__robExt_search_macros:w #1 } #2
  {
    \__robExt_if_letter:nTF {#2}
      { \__robExt_search_macros_aux:w #2 }
      { \__robExt_search_macros:w }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__robExt_search_macros_aux:w #1~
  {
    \cs_if_exist_use:c { __robExt_action_#1: }
    \__robExt_search_macros:w
  }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \__robExt_if_letter:n #1 { TF }
  {
    \bool_lazy_or:nnTF
      {
        \bool_lazy_and_p:nn
          { \int_compare_p:nNn { `#1 } > { `a - 1 } }
          { \int_compare_p:nNn { `#1 } < { `z + 1 } }
      }
      {
        \bool_lazy_and_p:nn
          { \int_compare_p:nNn { `#1 } > { `A - 1 } }
          { \int_compare_p:nNn { `#1 } < { `Z + 1 } }
      }
      \prg_return_true:
      \prg_return_false:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\__robExt_setup_protected_action:Nn \vegetable
  { \typeout { \noexpand \vegetable used } }
\__robExt_setup_protected_action:Nn \fruit
  { \typeout { \noexpand \fruit used } }

\__robExt_search_macros:n {I like \vegetable and \fruit.}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

prints

```
\vegetable used
\fruit used
```

to the log/terminal.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do have a lot of control symbol in practice, but this method is interesting as well! How do you do the benchmark ? I use `time` but it is not really precise nor constant.

Comment: @tobiasBora `l3benchmark`. But it gives relatively inconsistent results on Windows in general, on Unixoid systems it gives pretty reliable results.