# Efficiency of expl3 vs legacy tex

Tags: latex3

I start to appreciate the Latex3 expl library for the nice abstractions it gives (e.g. strings, lists…), but I also want to create a code as efficient as possible as it is often my bottle neck. In practice, I often do a mix of legacy code and expl code, like `\def\mymacro` and `\ifdefined\mymacro` instead of `\cs_set:Nn \mymacro: {}` and `\cs_exist:NTF \mymacro:`… So here are my questions:

In general, is legacy code more efficient than expl functions, and what is the order of magnitude of the difference? For instance, is using `\def` quicker than `\cs_set`? I would expect expl code to be always slower since I would expect it to expand to the legacy code first, but I might be wrong.

To give maybe a more concrete example, wipet provided [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700842/116348), while I would naturally try to implement it myself using a token list and `\tl_map_inline` with some checks like `\if_cs_exist:w`… He also recreates the concept of list using `\addto` while I would use a `\seq` (which are in my experience quite inefficient to build, but maybe I used them poorly?)… Is it possible to create a code as efficient in LaTeX3, or should I just stick to legacy code for parts that must be efficient?

And more generally, what are the structures that I could efficiently use from LaTeX3?

And is it fine to mix both legacy and expl3 codes?

Comment: It depends partly what you mean by 'efficient': for example, both `l3regex` and `l3fp` are basically written in primitives-renamed, but something like the `hooks` code or `siunitx` mainly uses higher-level constructs

Comment: AFAIK `\cs_set:Nn` is not as efficient as `\def`, because it has to analyze the name of the command sequence and puzzle a `\cs_set:Npn` with argument specification from the name. But `\cs_set:Npn` is `\long\def` and therefore almost efficient as `\def` (or `\long\def`). Almost, because it is still not a primitive but a protected macro, that has to be expanded.

Comment: BTW: IMHO the common definition of efficiency is to much "execution based". By this I mean that only execution resources such as memory and time are taken into account. Additional work during implementation is not taken into account, nor are extensive tests of the code and its correctness. If these are taken into account, well-documented and tested functions such as those of LaTeX3 have a clear advantage over constantly reinventing the wheel with the help of TeX primitives.

Comment: most expl3 is _far_ more efficient than a typical user would write to do the  same thing, but most users would never write a regex engine in tex, so efficiency is the wrong thing to ask about here.

Comment: Mixing legacy code an l3 code is another question. I would not use legacy commands or primitives in l3 code if a corresponding l3 function exists. For example in l3 code I would always use `\exp_after:wN` instead of `\expandafter`. But for several typeset features you still need to use legacy code, because there do not exist l3 functions, e.g., footnotes, page headers (but there are things already changing), sections, tables, environments, …

Comment: `is using \def quicker than \cs_set? I` well yes of course it is, as all commands are defined using `\def` in the end. It is impossible to speed things up by adding layers of macro expansion.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think the set of people who would think 'I know, I'll write a regex engine in TeX' is pretty well-defined ...

Comment: @JosephWright at least it doesn't intersect with people who'd write an xml parser in tex.

Comment: "most expl3 is far more efficient than a typical user would write...". I am not sure. I see that typical tasks for typesetting is much more efficient in OpTeX than in LaTeX. It can be seen by fmt file size, by number of lines in log file when \tracingall etc. And the differences are not small, they are orders of magnitude different.

Comment: I wouldn't call it legacy code, but natural TeX code. Of course, I don't mix this natural TeX code with expl3, because I am using only natural TeX code.

Answer (score 12):

Any abstraction will always add to the time taken for operations. However, there is always a balance between absolute maximum speed, flexibility of code and clarity. For example, the higher-level conditionals in `expl3` (`\tl_if_eq:NNTF`, for example) are set up such that they can handle arbitrary material in the two branches. That has a non-zero impact on performance compared with `\if_meaning:w` (the `\ifx` primitive renamed). However, it is *very* rare that the team worry about this, even in relatively low-level code. The only places where 'just the primitives renamed' are used are

- In early set-up (`l3basics`)
- In `l3regex`
- In `l3fp`

For `l3fp` and `l3regex`, the need to rally 'push' TeX means we need to use every trick we can. However, that applies almost nowhere else. If you want an extreme example, the `tl` data type uses `\edef\<name>{\unexpanded{<content>}` under the hood: that is very very slightly slower than `\def\<name>{<content>}` but allows `#` tokens, and it's so little real-world impact we prefer consistency over performance.

As an example of more 'user level' code, in `siunitx` I don't worry too much about using higher-level `expl3` constructs as and when they are useful. What I do worry about is the nature of data structures. If you look at the v3 code, I use a `prop` for collecting units: these are open-ended lists with multiple parts, and this flexible data structure makes sense. However, for numbers, I use a custom approach: a fixed number of brace groups inside a `tl`. This makes sense there as I can do 'classical' argument number manipulation to extract and add material.

It's also worth remembering we are comparing here `expl3` code that has decades of work (either directly by the team or by incorporating ideas from across the TeX world) with primitive code written by you. My own experience is that `expl3` is better written than arbitrary stuff I've done. In `siunitx`, v1 is *slower* than v2 even though v2 is written in `expl3` and v1 is not: it's all hand-coded by me. Now, I could (today) take all of the `expl3` experience and use that to write out myself each loop, data structure, etc., I use: I thought about that, and it was a complete pain in the neck.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149707/discussion-on-answer-by-joseph-wright-efficiency-of-expl3-vs-legacy-tex); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.